# How to prove that the inverse of the given continuous function is not continuous

Tags: continuity

I have the following problem: Consider the identity map $id: C_{max} \rightarrow C_{int}$ where $C_{max}$ is the metric space $C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ of continuous real valued function defined on $[a,b]$ equipped with the metric $d_{max}(f,g) = \max|f(x)-g(x)|$, and $C_{int}$ is $C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ equipped with the integral metric, $d_{int}(f,g) = \int_{a}^b |f(x) - g(x)| dx$.
Show that $id$ is a continuous linear bijection (an isomorphism) but its inverse is not continuous.

I proved continuity in the following manner: Note that it is trivially clear that the identity map $id$ is a bijection. We must then show that $id$ is continuous. For any given $\epsilon > 0$, suppose that $d_{max}(f,g) = \max|f - g| < \delta$ for $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$. Then we notice that

\begin{align} 
d_{int}(f,g) &= \int^a_b|f - g|dx \\
&< \int^a_b\delta \\
&= \delta(b - a) \\
&<  \epsilon.
\end{align}

However, I'm absolutely stuck on showing that the inverse of ${id}^{-1}$ is not continuous. My intuition says to us proof by contradiction, but I don't know what to do here. How would I begin going about proving that fact that ${id}^{-1}$ is not continuous?

Comment: hint: $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of functions $$f_n(x) := \max(1 - n|x|,0)$$ $C_{\text{int}}([-1,1])$-converge to $0$, but $‖ f_n - 0 ‖_{C_{\text{max}}} = 1 \not\to0$.